# Android - Signed apk not run in mobile device

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am facing very strange problem. When I directly copy APK from bin folder of project and paste in mobile phone SD card. And install it, it working fine. While I do same with export signed APK from Android Tool in project and placed APK in SD card. It install successfully but not run. I do not know why this is happen. I also you progaurad in app. Is it cause of crashing app??

Here is logcat output

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.globalassignmenthelp, PID: 7708
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "android.view.View q.a(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)"
at r.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at com.globalassignmenthelp.Perspective.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3571)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3644)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:381)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2159)
at com.globalassignmenthelp.Perspective.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5966)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2408)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Please help and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try remove current app and reinstall new app

Comment: I did same, but still facing same error.

Comment: Apk file in ``bin`` folder have signed with ``Debug key``, but when you export , apk will signed with ``Release key``

Comment: @ Danh- So what i have to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you post full logcat, I think we can see the cause of error in this.

Comment: You can set same key for both debug and release mode. Then run the app from Android studio again.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html this is useful for you

Comment: Try adb install MyApp.apk in a shell from your ./bin folder while the phone is attached to USB.

Comment: @QuangTV - I already posted full logcat output

Comment: @DanhDC - I am using eclipse. How I use same key for debug and release mode?

Comment: One simple step to identify the issue is remove the `proguard` configuration for `release` mode and generate signed APK and test it. If it works then there's a problem with `proguard` config. This kind of scenario happens because of wrong proguard configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using wrong proguard. This type of problem comes when something wrong with progurad. Try to replace your project.properties with this code- 
here is link - [Progurad Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/et9b0vmmimvvr7w/progurad%20code?dl=0)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
add this code to proguard.txt

if you are using v4

 # support-v4
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }

if you are using v7

# support-v7
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: That did it for me. Wish I understood why this wasn't part of the default proguard-android.txt